# Oracle 11g - Building a Type 2 SCD based on existing historical data in a relational model

Tags: oracle, database-design, etl, scd

I'm an ETL developer that's currently being tasked with developing [a type 2 SCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) from existing historical data in a relational database. I'm perfectly capable of creating a type 2 SCD that's responsible for tracking future changes to the data, but I'm completely useless when it comes to the task at hand.

The relational model is in our ODS . Based on that relational model, I'm supposed to build flat records in our DW dimension. There are multiple attributes which need to be monitored for changes, each in specific related tables in the relational model. Historical changes must be kept on a daily basis, and if multiple changes to the same attribute occur on the same day, only the last subsists.

How can I tackle this? I'm lost. Thanks in advance.

P.S. we're talking tables with 20-30 million rows and multiple attributes that may change at any given time and therefore must result in a new record in the SCD.

Comment: ETL SCD ODS DW WTF TLA?

Comment: ETL - Extract / Transform / Load
SCD - Slowly Changing Dimension
ODS - Operational Data Store
DW - Data Warehouse

Comment: Often an SCD 2 is required to track changes to a source table that doesn't in itself track changes - it overwrites. Are you saying that you have a source where changes are tracked (in some fashion) but you need to now model that in an SCD2? To pose any kind of algorithm we'd need to have some idea of what your source data looks like

Comment: Given a trivial example: You have a transactional table that has one column indicating when someone changes their address. To convert this to an SCD you'd just need to add the end date to the existing data. Given another trivial example: You have a table that has values overwritten each time. There is no way to build an SCD2 off this because you don't know what the prior value is unless you want to painstakingly apply database restores (and since you're using Oracle the operative word is *pain* here)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, the source tracks the changes in all the tables in the relational model. In the SCS, a change may be triggered by 6 or 7 (don't recall correctly) related attributes, all in different tables in the relational model. The SCD must flatten all these different attributes into one record that can change over time, if changes in the underlying attributes have occurred.

Comment: So first thing is to denormalise all the related source tables into one row. So if you have six tables, all with many to one relationships... join them into one flat row.... now I guess each of those six table might have a difference change date right?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, all related tables track the creation and change dates.

Comment: What tool are you using to build SCD's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will indeed be painful. I'm assuming from your question that the tables containing the attribute values are currently varying independently (or you wouldn't need to ask the question).

If you have a table 'Table1' containing 'Key', 'Attribute1' and 'Effective From','Effective To' columns, then you can 'explode' that table into a virtual table in the form 'Key','Attribute1','Date', projecting out one row for every date where that attribute was current.

(Note that you probably **don't** want to do this as a ranged join against your date dimension, because this will be a [Triangular Join](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/) (ie perform really badly), you probably need to explode the rows in an ETL tool/programmatically)

If you perform this process across multiple tables, you will have a set of tables giving you the full day-by-day snapshot of each attribute for every day that you care about. It's then fairly easy to join those tables based on 'FK' and 'Date' to give you the complete daily snapshot across all of the attribute values.

Then, of course, you need to run this though another process to collapse rows with the same Key, contiguous dates and all the same attribute values, ie 'unexplode' the rows, back into 'effective from','effective to' form. Note again, that this is fundamentally a row-by-row operation (or at very least a windowing function), and a set-based approach will perform very badly. Personally I'd just stream it all though some .net/java code to achieve this.

Given data volumes this will take a while, but should be achievable.